# How To keep track of counter variables in ruby, block, for, each, do

Tags: ruby, loops, variables, counter

I forget how to keep track of the position of the loops in Ruby. Usually I write in JavaScript, AS3, Java, etc.

`each`:

```
counter = 0
Word.each do |word,x|
   counter += 1
   #do stuff
end
```

`for`:

same thing

`while`:

same thing

`block`

```
Word.each  {|w,x| }
```

This one I really don't know about.

Comment: What's your question? I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Ah, I knew it was to vague. How to keep track of counter variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to Ruby 1.8's `Array#each_with_index` method, many enumerating methods in Ruby 1.9 return an Enumerator when called without a block; you can then call the `with_index` method to have the enumerator also pass along the index:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = *('a'..'g')
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]

irb(main):002:0> a.map
#=> #<Enumerator:0x28bfbc0>

irb(main):003:0> a.select
#=> #<Enumerator:0x28cfbe0>

irb(main):004:0> a.select.with_index{ |c,i| i%2==0 }
#=> ["a", "c", "e", "g"]

irb(main):005:0> Hash[ a.map.with_index{ |c,i| [c,i] } ]
#=> {"a"=>0, "b"=>1, "c"=>2, "d"=>3, "e"=>4, "f"=>5, "g"=>6}
```

If you want `map.with_index` or `select.with_index` (or the like) under Ruby 1.8.x, you can either do this boring-but-fast method:

```
i = 0
a.select do |c|
  result = i%2==0
  i += 1
  result
end
```

or you can have more functional fun:

```
a.zip( (0...a.length).to_a ).select do |c,i|
  i%2 == 0
end.map{ |c,i| c }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use `each_with_index` instead of `each`, you'll get an index along with the element. So you can do:

```
Word.each_with_index do |(word,x), counter|
   #do stuff
end
```

For `while` loops you'll still have to keep track of the counter yourself.

Comment: Yeah this is what I'm look for but a bigger picture of them all.

Comment: @Sam: I'm not sure what kind of bigger picture you mean.

Comment: lol, I guess I don't remember. I guess what I mean is like in javascript you can initialize the counter in the loop but in ruby this doesn't seem intuitive because the counter should just be there. no?

Answer (score 3):

A capital W would mean it's a constant which most likely mean it's a class or a module not an instance of a class. I guess you could have a class return an enumerable using each but that seems very bizarre.

To remove the confusing extra junk and the, possibly, incorrectly capitalized example I would make my code look like this.

```
words = get_some_words()
words.each_with_index do |word, index|
  puts "word[#{index}] = #{word}"
end
```

I'm not sure what Sepp2K was doing with the weird (word,x) thing.